# After running `swift build` dependencies are downloaded by class is not found

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create an example with the **Swift Package Manager** where I am creating a small *library*, host it on my github and then use this library as a depdendency to create an *executable* Swift program.

This is my setup:

### library

[image]

**MyXMLHelper.swift**

```
class MyXMLHelper {

  static func enclose(text: String, withXMLTag tag: String) -> String {
    let openingTag = "<\(tag)>"
    let closingTag = "</\(tag)>"
    return openingTag + text + closingTag
  }

}
```

**Package.swift**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "XMLHelper"
)
```

You're also welcome to check out the original version on my [github](https://github.com/nikolasburk/xml-util).

### executable (cmd line)

**main.swift**

```
import XMLHelper

print("Please enter a text you would like to enclose: ", terminator: "")
let text = readLine()!

print("Please enter the XML tag: ", terminator: "")
let tag = readLine()!

let result = MyXMLHelper.enclose(text: text, withXMLTag: tag)
print("Result: \(result)")
```

**Package.swift**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "XML_application",
  dependencies: [
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/nikolasburk/xml-util",
             majorVersion: 2),
  ]
)
```

After running `swift build`, the folder structure looks like this:

[image]

So, `swift build` successfully downloads the dependency, but then it also gives me the following error:

```
/Users/nburk/Projects/makeschool/tutorials/swift-package-manager-demo/xml-app/main.swift:9:14: error: use of unresolved identifier 'MyXMLHelper'
let result = MyXMLHelper.enclose(text: text, withXMLTag: tag)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-08-24-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/nburk/Projects/makeschool/tutorials/swift-package-manager-demo/xml-app/.build/debug.yaml
```

Does anyone know why that is? Why can't it find the class `MyXMLHelper`, shouldn't it be visible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your class is not public.

In *MyXMLHelper.swift*, it should be declared like this:

```
public class MyXMLHelper {
```

or, if you want to be able to subclass it (Xcode 8 beta 6):

```
open class MyXMLHelper {
```